# How to modify this regex expression to accept hyphens?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following Regex (in PHP) that I am using.

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9&\'\s]+$/'
```

It currently accepts alpha-numerics only. I need to modify it to accept hyphens (i.e. the character '-' without the quotes obviously) as well.

So it will accept strings like 'bart-simpson' OR 'bond-007'  etc.

Can anyone explain how to modiy the pattern?

Comment: a regex like this '/^[-a-zA-Z0-9&\'\s]+$/' , will make it possible to create strings like: "----" or "-something"... is this the desired behaviour? what kind of strings do you expect? do you have limitations or everything within those characters is allowed??

Comment: @acmatos: and the existing regex matchs `"&&&'  &"`, so what is your point?

Comment: it currently accepts ampersand, single quote and whitespace characters apart from alphanumerics.

Comment: I don't have a point, just asking if that's the desired behaviour for the regex... The examples look like usernames to me so, I wouldn't want a user with ampersands, quotes, whitespaces or - but that's me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the character class:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9&\'\s-]+$/'
```

Comment: Hold on, I suspect I did not reload my page during testing. I'll try again

Comment: Yup, I made a silly mistake, I edited the wrong regex in the file. Problem sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a hyphen at the end of the character group within brackets. This ought to work:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9&\'\s-]+$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the hyphen at the front, to make it fairly obvious that it isn't part of a range:

```
'/^[-a-zA-Z0-9&\'\s]+$/'
```